# How to stop an animated scrollbar at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have coded very well a beautifully-animated scrollbar, but when it reaches the footer (bottom) of the page, it does not stop.

A demo is [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/my8swy0u/).

```js
$(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

```css
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
        #page-wrap { width: 600px; margin: 15px auto; }
        p { margin: 0 0 15px 0; }
        p:first-child { background: #fffcde; padding: 10px; }
        #sidebar ul { background: #eee; padding: 10px; }
        li { margin: 0 0 0 20px; }
        #main { width: 390px; float: left; }
        #sidebar { width: 190px; float: right; }
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
/**
 * For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout)
 */
.cf {
    *zoom:1;
}
footer{
    text-align: center;
    height:30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap" class="cf">
 
     <div id="title-area">

      <h1>ДЕМО</h1>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
        
  </div>
    
  <div id="main">

    <p>ПРОКРУЧИВАЙТЕ СТРАНИЦУ ВНИЗ!</p>
  
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>  
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  
  </div>
  
  <div id="sidebar">
    
     <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>  <li><a href="index.html">ДЕМО 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="css.html">ДЕМО 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="reveal.html">ДЕМО 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
<footer>
    THIS IS FOOTER!!!
</footer>
```

Comment: "This code bad working in this site http://stackoverflow.com/"
What does that even mean??

Answer (score 0):

**Jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/my8swy0u/1/

Just add condition that stops rest of function if it's near end.

```
$(function () {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() - 800) return;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: not universal code... if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() - 800) return;